# Behaviour of L4 load balancers on server addition to the pool

Tags: load-balancing, azure-load-balancer

As I understand L4 level load balancers, e.g. Azure Load Balancer, are almost alway stateless, i.e. they do not keep per-flow state on which server handles which TCP connection.

What is the behaviour of such load balancers in case of server additions to DIP pool? Do they lose some of the connections since corresponding packets get sent over to the new server?

Comment: Hi rekli, do you have any concern about my reply?

Comment: Hi Nancy, I upvoted your answer, however my question was about internals of load balancers, whereas your answer is more user visible features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [Ananta: Cloud Scale Load Balancing - SIGCOMM](https://conferences.sigcomm.org/sigcomm/2013/papers/sigcomm/p207.pdf) paper which actually says that per-flow state is stored in one MUX machine (not replicated) which receives the associated traffic from the router. Hence server addition doesn't affect existing TCP connections as long as MUX machines stay as is.

Answer (score 1):

> As I understand L4 level load balancers, e.g. Azure Load Balancer, are
>   almost alway stateless, i.e. they do not keep per-flow state on which
>   server handles which TCP connection.

That is not true.

By default, Azure Load Balancer distributes network traffic equally among multiple VM instances in a 5-tuple hash distribution mode (the source IP, source port, destination IP, destination port, and protocol type). You can also configure **session affinity**. For more information, see [Load Balancer distribution mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-distribution-mode). For session affinity, the mode uses a 2-tuple (source IP and destination IP) or 3-tuple (source IP, destination IP, and protocol type) hash to map traffic to the available servers. **By using source IP affinity, connections that are initiated from the same client computer go to the same DIP endpoint**.

> What is the behaviour of such load balancers in case of server
>   additions to DIP pool? Do they lose some of the connections since
>   corresponding packets get sent over to the new server?

They do not lose connection.

The load balancing rules work rely on health probes to detect the failure of an application on a backend instance. Refer to [probe down behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-custom-probe-overview#probedown). If a backend instance's health probe fails, established TCP connections to this backend instance **continue**. For a new TCP connection, it will connect to the remaining healthy instances. Load Balancer **does not terminate or originate flows**. It's a pass-through service (does not terminate TCP connections) and the flow is always between the client and the VM's guest OS and application.